# 301 RedirectMatch - Many URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the below htaccess code in place:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I am trying to automatically redirect pages to include 'in' per the new URL structure. The two RedirectMatch lines above work for two scenarios, but I need a third scenario to be possible.

First RedirectMatch line works for cities (single name):

domain.com/music-classes-dallas-tx.html ===> domain.com/music-classes-in-dallas-tx.html

Second RedirectMatch line works for states:

domain.com/music-classes-texas.html ===> domain.com/music-classes-in-texas.html

What I now need is for the RedirectMatch to work with city names that have 2-3 words. For example, The Colony TX or New Orleans LA. The code above doesn't catch these.

Someone told me to use the below, but it's causing a redirect loop and throws in a bunch of in-in-in-in-in-in-in into the URL.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(.+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try it with these rewrite rules. This tested out for me with a space in the name. And make sure to clear your cache before trying them.

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(?!in)([^/]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(?!in)([^-]+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html [R=301,L]
```

With that rule this works for me.

```
http://example.com/music-classes-dallas-tx.html
```

or

```
http://example.com/music-classes-san-antonio-tx.html
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be looping again with the redirect loop error:
domain.com/music-classes-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-in-dallas-tx.html

Comment: @user1858780 my fault. I tested it with `.htaccess tester site`. I actually tested this in my system and rule will work as expected. I edited the first rule.

Comment: I just noticed it's working with san-diego-ca but not new-jersey. So the states with two words aren't redirecting for some reason, but two words + state initials works. Any ideas around this? Thanks!

Comment: @user1858780 can you ask this in a new question and I'll answer it for you. let me know when you ask. This also helps your rep.

Comment: @user1858780 should be simple. change `(?!in)([^-]+)\.html` to this `(?!in)([^/]+)\.html` in the 2nd line.

Comment: crap, now my normal URLs are having issues. Example, domain.com/careers-jobs-music-degree.html is turning into domain.com/careers-jobs-in-music-degree.html - how can this be prevented?

Comment: I have added a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562914/301-redirectmatch-issue

Answer (score 2):

You should be using rewrite rules instead of `RedirectMatch`, because you have a wordpress installation which has routing rules. Those could cause the redirects to get wonky.

The best way to handle this is probably do a negative look-ahead for the "in" and redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(?!in-)(.+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This actually works for all city/state formats. Thanks!! Only issue is that it messed up normal URLs too... example: 

domain.com/careers-jobs-culinary-arts-degree.html goes to domain.com/careers-jobs-in-culinary-arts-degree.

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: @user1858780 how do you tell the difference between cities and non-cities?

Comment: The answer above yours actually works now after the edit the poster made... all set. Thanks for your help!