# 301 RedirectMatch - Issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I posted a question here which I got an answer for, but now I've identified an issue with the code.

Original Question:

[301 RedirectMatch - Many URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401716/301-redirectmatch-many-urls)

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(?!in)([^/]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(?!in)([^/]+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html [R=301,L]
```

While the above fixed all the issues with the URLs, I noticed my normal URLs are having issues. Example, domain.com/careers-jobs-music-degree.html is turning into domain.com/careers-jobs-in-music-degree.html - the 'in' is being added to other URLs that don't have 'music-classes' in the URL. Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the normal URL's real URLs or are they fake as well?

Comment: those are real and in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the rules this way so real URLs shouldn't be affected.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(?!in)([^/]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(?!in)([^/]+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, everything works except normal URLs like: http://www.domain.com/the-best-music-schools.html

Comment: Also, is there an option if there is a URL with multi-word cities to change like this:  music-classes-sandiego-ca.html to music-classes-in-san-diego-ca.html... so it's adding the -in- and also splitting up sandiego to san-diego.

Comment: are the URLs that are redirected to in real or fake? Also to answer your 2nd comment, no there is not a way because how does Apache no that SanDiego is supposed to have a space in it? It's just another word.

Comment: These specific pages like domain.com/the-best-music-schools.html do not exist if you have the -in- in the URL. hope that answers the question

Comment: is this even possible to do?